# Mock a python object delegating magic methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that mostly displays outwardly as a set of ids, but not entirely. Think this:

```
class PoundIds(object):
    ....
    @property
    def cats(self):
        return self.cats

    @property
    def dogs(self):
        return self.dogs

    @property
    def animal_ids(self):
        return set(dog.id for dog in self.dogs) | set(cat.id for cat in self.cats) | 

    def __contains__(self, id):
        return id in self.animal_ids

    def __iter__(self, id):
        return self.animal_ids.__iter__()
```

I am now testing this object, in a way that will only be using the list of ids it provides. Is there a way to mock out the object as a specific set of integers, passing magic methods through to the encapsulated set? So if I write `if a in Foo():`, I want the mock Foo to be calling `a in Foo().animal_ids`, and so on for other magic methods.

Comment: What do you mean `through to the encapsulated set`? Also can you add some info to your question like def init, and console examples of input output? It will help a lot to determine what to patch and with what.

Comment: I mean that if you call contains or iter, the mock will call contains or iter on the set.

Comment: init and I/O are totally irrelevant; they are not the same in my example code here as in the code I'm concerned about, and I am not testing them here.